# this.props.getEvents is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have getEvents defined in exported in my `eventActions.js`. I cannot figure out why I am getting this error. I imported the function and the filepath is correct.

**Component**

```
import { getEvents } from "../../actions/eventActions";

...

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.getCurrentProfile();
  this.props.getEvents();
}
```

**eventActions.js**

```
// Get Events
export const getEvents = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setEventsLoading());
  axios
    .get("/api/events")
    .then(res =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_EVENTS,
        payload: res.data
      })
    )
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_EVENTS,
        payload: null
      })
    );
};
```

Comment: You are importing it into the module, but are you really giving `getEvents` as a prop to the component? Try to just write `getEvents();` instead.

Comment: That worked. Why am I able to call `this.props.getCurrentProfile()`, but not events? PS: Thanks for always answering my react questions!

Comment: You're welcome! That's hard to say without seeing the code where you use your component. You might be passing in `getCurrentProfile` as a prop to the component when you use it, or you might inject it with Redux `connect`, etc.

Comment: I didn't inject it with connect! That's what happened!

Comment: Thank you for dropping knowledge as always!

Answer (score 1):

`Props` is something which is passed by the parent component to its child component. Here, you are importing it from a file and not passing from a parent component.

You can simply use - `getEvents()` instead of `this.props.getEvents()`.

Comment: Why am I able to use? `this.props.getCurrentProfile()` I tried calling it like `getCurrentProfile()`, but it doesn't load in? Yours and Tholle's suggestion worked.

Comment: Because, that may have been passed from a parent component of the component you have mentioned in the question. Can you post the code where this component is being created?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't inject it with connect. Above suggestions work as well. I figure I will need this outside this component, so this best option would be to inject it with connect.

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getCurrentProfile, deleteAccount, getEvents }
)(Dashboard);
```